# SQL: avg() function in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the salary of all employees whose `sal` (salary) is greater than the average salary of all employees, however I get the error "invalid use of group function". How can I use `avg()` function in `where` clause?

```sql
select   sal 
from emp
where sal> (avg(sal)) ;
```

Comment: Is your question:  "How can I use `avg()` in the `where` clause"?  Or is your question:  "How can I get the appropriate set of employees"?  These are very different questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AVG in WHERE clause like that. Try this query:

```
SELECT sal FROM emp WHERE sal > (SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use subquery:

```
select   sal 
from emp
where sal> (select avg(sal) avgsal from emp) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg` as a `window function`, this normally yields better performance over a sub-query:

```
select Sal from (
    select Sal, Avg(Sal) over() avgSal
    from Employees
)e
where Sal > avgSal
```